# How to determine matching coefficients in a Effective Field Theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, effective-field-theory

Assume that I have the Lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L}_{UV} 
=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\partial_{\mu} \phi\right)^{2}-m_{L}^{2} \phi^{2}+\left(\partial_{\mu} H\right)^{2}-M^{2} H^{2}\right] 
-\frac{\lambda_{0}}{4 !} \phi^{4}-\frac{\lambda_{2}}{4} \phi^{2} H^{2},$$
where $\phi$ is a light scalar field with mass $m_L$ and $H$ a heavy one with mass $M$. Let the Lagrangian of the effective field theory (EFT) be
$$\mathcal{L}_{EFT} = \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\partial_{\mu} \phi\right)^{2}-m^{2} \phi^{2}\right]-C_{4} \frac{\phi^{4}}{4 !}-\frac{C_{6}}{M^{2}} \frac{\phi^{6}}{6 !}.$$

Assume that I have calculated the $4$-point function up to $1$-loop order and regularized it correctly (renormalization scale $\mu$). The results are:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{M}_{4}^{\mathrm{EFT}} &=-C_{4}+\frac{C_{4}^{2}}{32 \pi^{2}}[f(s, m)+f(t, m)+f(u, m)] \\
&+\frac{3 C_{4}^{2}}{32 \pi^{2}}\left(\log \left(\frac{\mu^{2}}{m^{2}}\right)+2\right)+\frac{C_{6} m^{2}}{32 \pi^{2} M^{2}}\left(\log \left(\frac{\mu^{2}}{m^{2}}\right)+1\right)\\\\
\mathcal{M}_{4}^{\mathrm{UV}} & \approx-\lambda_{0}+\frac{3 \lambda_{0}^{2}}{32 \pi^{2}}\left(\log \left(\frac{\mu^{2}}{m^{2}}\right)+2\right)+\frac{3 \lambda_{2}^{2}}{32 \pi^{2}}\left(\log \left(\frac{\mu^{2}}{M^{2}}\right)\right)+\frac{m^{2} \lambda_{2}^{2}}{48 \pi^{2} M^{2}} \\
&+\frac{\lambda_{0}^{2}}{32 \pi^{2}}[f(s, m)+f(t, m)+f(u, m)].
\end{align*}
$$

The matching at tree-level resulted in:
$$m^2=m_L^2,\qquad C_4 = \lambda_0,\qquad C_6=0.$$
I would now like to perform the matching at one-loop, i.e. we again demand $\mathcal{M}_4^{EFT}= \mathcal{M}_4^{UV}+O(M^{-2})$.

#### Problem

We have two unknowns, $C_4$ and $C_6$, that need to be expressed in terms of $\lambda_0, \lambda_2, m, M, etc.$. But $\mathcal{M}_4^{EFT}= \mathcal{M}_4^{UV}+O(M^{-2})$ gives us only one equation.. I don't see how we can determine both coefficients with only the above information.

#### Notes

I'm reading Adam Falkowski's lecture notes, see [here](https://userswww.pd.infn.it/%7Eferuglio/Falkowski.pdf). In section 2.3, p.~24, he performs the matching with only the above information...

Answer (score 1):

> I don't see how we can determine both coefficients with only the above information.

**We can't.**

We need one observable for each EFT quantity that we want to match to the UV. The physical mass $m_\text{phys}^2$ allows to 1-loop match the EFT mass $m$ to the UV quantities, and the 2-2 scattering amplitude allows to 1-loop match the EFT coupling $C_4$ to the UV quantities. If you wanted to 1-loop match the EFT coupling $C_6$, you'd need another equation, as you correctly observe, coming from an observable such as the 3-3 scattering amplitude.
The 3-3 scattering amplitude is *very messy* and the author doesn't even give the calculations for the tree-level matching with the $\lambda_1$ coupling turned on, but only the results (eq. $2.16$).

If you want to match the coupling $C_6$ without the messy calculations, the author provides in part 3 a functional method to obtain it far more easily: the result is in eq. $3.47$.